# a simple pointed colormap or legend in matlab

Tags: matlab, legend, imshow, colormap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36ZO9.png)
 like the image attached,I want to have a pointed colormap or legend besides the image to guide others what does these colors means. like color-text box.

what should I use? I think legend is for plotting and it does not appear near image show.

Comment: Why not use a legend rather than a colorbar?

Comment: @Suever ok that's a good idea. but each color is like a line.isn't it?

Comment: @Suever Do you know how to use legend with rgb color?